# Does the <form name="abc"> add an abc object to a $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have code that adds a form and gives it a name. This is the only way I have been able to get the validation working.

However when I look at the scope I don't seem to be able to see any reference to the form name. Can someone explain how this is added.

Does the `<form ..`   element somehow dynamically create a form object or do I have to create an empty object first?

Comment: As far as I know it creates a new controller with the name "abc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by [the documentation for the `form` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form):

> If the `name` attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.

Therefore, you have access to a [`FormController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) object in your scope. That's why you can use it like any other variable, when you do something like that, for instance:

```
<input
    type="submit"
    value="Submit !"
    ngDisabled="formName.$invalid"
/>
```